# foreach (Example item in list) Json only get first Item?

Tags: c#, json, foreach

I have a json list that gives me 17e rows(Item), however when I insert the json data into my sql server database I only get the first row(item) in the list and it seems that it skips all others.

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

```
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Orders (orderId,consignmentNumber,itemNumbers,country,orderType,paymentTransactionId,priceInOre,paidAt,orderNumber,articleName) VALUES (@orderId,@consignmentNumber,@itemNumbers,@country,@orderType,@paymentTransactionId,@priceInOre,@paidAt,@orderNumber,@articleName)", con);                 
        
        foreach (Example item in list)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderId", item.OrderId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@consignmentNumber", item.ConsignmentNumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemNumbers", item.ItemNumbers.First());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", item.Country);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderType", item.OrderType);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paidAt", item.PaidAt);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paymentTransactionId", item.PaymentTransactionId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priceInOre", item.PriceInOre);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@articleName", item.ArticleName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderNumber", item.OrderNumber);
        }
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems that you are executing your insert after the foreach loop, so only the last built cmd is executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only executing the query once, outside the for loop. Structure your code as follows:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Orders (orderId,consignmentNumber,itemNumbers,country,orderType,paymentTransactionId,priceInOre,paidAt,orderNumber,articleName) VALUES (@orderId,@consignmentNumber,@itemNumbers,@country,@orderType,@paymentTransactionId,@priceInOre,@paidAt,@orderNumber,@articleName)", con);                 
    
    foreach (Example item in list)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        // ... (set parameters)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    con.Close();
}
```